# How to get particular lines string length from DOM element by using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string like this (**hello how are you? hello how are you? hello how are you? hello how are you?**). I am rendering this string in DOM element with **80px** of width.

I am counting number of string lines by using below code. Now it returns number of lines displayed in UI.

Now i need to count second line's string length. How to get second line's string length? is there any possible solution to do this?

```js
function numberOfLines() {
  var divHeight = document.getElementById('content').offsetHeight
  var lineHeight = parseInt(document.getElementById('content').style.lineHeight);
  var lines = divHeight / lineHeight;
  alert("Lines: " + Math.round(lines));
}
```

```html
<body onload="numberOfLines();">
  <div id="content" style="width: 80px; line-height: 20px">
    hello how are you? hello how are you? hello how are you? hello how are you?
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "second lines"?

Comment: 1st line string is "hello how" and 2nd line string is "are you?" and vise versa.